# Rails 7 app - getting 'uninitialized constant' error while referencing Model files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

running a rails 7.0.x app and running into an `uninitialized constant` error anytime it references a Model class that's in `app/models`

so I have a service class in

```
app/services/sales_service.rb
```

Service Class:

```
class SalesService
  def gensalesdata
   print "TESTING: #{AuthorSale.last} \n"
  end
end
```

and it's invoked by a rake task:

```
task :testtask1 do
   SalesService.new.gensalesdata
end
```

It is making a call to a basic model file called `AuthorSale` , which is located in

```
app/models/author_sale.rb
```

the model file code is:

```
class AuthorSale < ApplicationRecord
end
```

and even if i do a simple `AuthorSale.last` call from the service class, i get that error:

```
uninitialized constant SalesService::AuthorSale
```

- ran a `bin/rails zeitwerk:check` check and it returned with a `Hold on, I am eager loading the application. All is good!` response
- `config.eager_load = true` is set in the `config/environments/development.rb` file
- went through dozens of other similar posts on SO and none of them seemed to solve my issue.
- The underlying table name in MySQL is `author_sales`
- The stranger issue is that this same code works just fine if i invoke it from the Rails console. It stops working if the code is run from the command line via a Rake task or from a web server

UPDATE:

- Two more issues discovered while debugging this that when i add this to `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
  config.eager_load = true
  print "#{ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths}"
```

the flow is not even entering that file even though the `RAILS_ENV` is set to `development`

and when i print out the same `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths` right inside the service class file, it prints out an empty array, which is further proof that the app is unable to find/load any of the `app/models` files

what am i missing?

Comment: please copy the content of your SalesSevice

Comment: @Maxence, i've updated the description to add the SalesService class content.

Comment: How do you call your service ?

Comment: @Maxence, thanks for the follow-up questions. I've added the additional detail on how the service is called to the description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to link your rake task to an environment :

```
task testtask1: :environment do
   SalesService.new.gensalesdata
end
```

Comment: That was it. Once i added the `:environment` to the task definition, it resolved the issue.